# Pass non-form html elements to Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api

I'm displaying search results on an angular page which will give the user the option to submit these to an API for further processing.

I'd like to know how I can access non-form elements/attributes from the view in my controller so I can send these to the required API.

**HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{book.title}}">
 <ion-content class="padding">
  <div class="list card">
   <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img ng-src="{{book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}}">
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{book.authors[0]}}</p>
   </div>

   <div class="item item-image">
    <img class="single-book-img" ng-src="{{book.imageLinks.thumbnail}}">
   </div>

  <div class="item item-body">
    <p>
    {{book.description}}
    </p>
    <p>
      <!--<a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
      <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>-->
      <button class="button button-balanced activated" data-ng-click="addBook($event)">Add to Products</button>
    </p>

    </div>

  </div>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I've used **data-ng-click="addBook($event)"**

**controller.js**

```
.controller('SingleBookCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,BookSearch){
  $scope.book = BookSearch.get($stateParams.bookId);
  $scope.addBook = function(event){
  console.log(event);
 }
})
```

In the controller file console.log the event and get a huge object.

I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way to get the data I need. This includes the img src as well as title and description and author.

Comment: pass the `book` object as argument

Comment: @charlietfl wow easy as that. Thank you so much.

Comment: And you don't even need to pass it as an argument. You already have it in your controller `$scope.book`.

Comment: You can access that in your `addBook` function. `$scope.addBook = function() { console.log($scope.book); }`